# Most efficient way of Extracting tags from multiple strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have an html page with multiple instances of the following tags:

```
<INCLUDEFILE-1-/var/somepath/file1.php>
<INCLUDEFILE-2-/var/somepath/file2.php>
<INCLUDEFILE-3-/var/somepath/file3.php>
<INCLUDEFILE-4-/var/somepath/file4.php>
<INCLUDEFILE-5-/var/somepath/file5.php>
```

What code can I use to extract all of the paths above? I have so far got the following code but cannot get it to work properly:

```
preg_match_all('/INCLUDEFILE[^"]+/m', $html, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++)
{
    $includefile = $result[0][$i];
}
```

I need to extract:

```
/var/somepath/file1.php
/var/somepath/file2.php
/var/somepath/file3.php
/var/somepath/file4.php
/var/somepath/file5.php
```

Can anyone see the obvious mistake(s)?!

Comment: Did you really mean to say `FILEINCLUDE` in your regex, instead of `INCLUDEFILE`?

Comment: Thanks Robert for pointing that out... I will correct and clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way to happiness:

```
$pattern = '`<INCLUDEFILE-\d+-\K/[^>\s]+`';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $results);
$results=$results[0];
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your regex slightly and added parenthesis to capture the subpattern you need. I didn't see quotes (") in the posted example so I changed to checking for ">" to detect the end. I also added the ungreedy modifier, you may try how it goes with or without ungreedy. I also check for result[1] which will contain the first subpattern matches.

```
preg_match_all('/<INCLUDEFILE-[0-9]+-([^>]+)>/Um', $html, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[1]); $i++)
{
    $includefile = $result[1][$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
$html = '
    <INCLUDEFILE-1-/var/somepath/file1.php>fadsf
    asdfasf<INCLUDEFILE-2-/var/somepath/file2.php>adsfaf
    <INCLUDEFILE-3-/var/somepath/file3.php>asdfadsf
    <INCLUDEFILE-4-/var/somepath/file4.php>
    <INCLUDEFILE-5-/var/somepath/file5.php>
';

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $html);
$files = array();

foreach($lines as $line)
{
    preg_match('/<INCLUDEFILE-\d+-(.+?)>/', $line, $match);
    if(!empty($match)) {
        $files[] = $match[1];
    }
}

var_dump($files);
```

Comment: It would be great to have them in an array, but as they can vary from page to page I'm looking for a more flexible method... the answer might be in using your preg_match I will try that!